# Formik + Yup: How to immediately validate form on mount?

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

I want to show field errors when form mounted. Not after submit.

Yup:

```
const validation = Yup.object().shape({
  field: Yup.string().required('Required')
});
```

Formik:

```
<Formik
  initialValues={initialValues}
  validationSchema={validation}
  validateOnMount
>
  ...
</Formik>
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

## The simple answer is

Pass `initialTouched` to `Formik` which will be an object with key of the fields you want to show the error message and the value `true` for those keys.

e.g.

```
<Formik
  initialValues={initialValues}
  initialTouched={{ 
    field: true,
  }}
  validationSchema={validation}
  validateOnMount
>
  ...
</Formik>
```

---

But there is alot of ways to do this, but you can create an component that call `validateForm` on the initial render

```
const ValidateOnMount = () => {
    const { validateForm } = useFormikContext()

    React.useEffect(() => {
        validateForm()
    }, [])

    // the return doesn't matter, it can return anything you want
    return <></>
}
```

---

You can also do the same using `validateOnMount` and setting `initialTouched` to true on all fields you want to display the error message (maybe you only want to show certain field's error message on the initial mount).

```
<Formik 
    validateOnMount
    initialValues={initialValues}
    validationSchema={validation}
    initialTouched={{ 
        field: true
    }}
    {...rest}
>
</Formik>
```

Where `initialTouched` should be an object that have keys to all fields that you want to validate that are in `initialValues` but with the value `true`, which means you already touched that field.

---

Another way to do this is only passing `validateOnMount` to `Formik` and display any error message without checking for `touched[name]`.
If you use [`ErrorMessage`](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/errormessage) from `formik`, it won't work because it checks for `touched[name] === true` to display the message, so you need to create your own way of displaying the error, but only checking for `errors[name]`.

Comment: Best answer I have found! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks I was missing the validateOnMount field

Answer (score 1):

There's a prop called `isInitialValid`.
Setting it to `false` solved my problem :)

Answer (score -1):

you can use errors and touched props, like this

```
<Formik 
    initialValues={initialValues} 
    validationSchema={validation} 
    validateOnMount 
> 
    {props => { 
        const { errors, touched } = props 
        return ( 
            <Form> 
                ... 
                {errors.field && touched.field ? <Error>{errors.field}</Error> : null} 
                ... 
            </Form> 
        )
    }
</Formik>
```

Comment: Yeah, I show errors but only when touched the field. How can I see errors before this? Thank you!