# Yup & React Hook Form: How to validate onChange rather than onSubmit

Tags: javascript, yup, react-hook-form

I have an onChange function `onNameChange` that contains a `valid` variable that should match the yup validation of the name field. The problem is that the valid variable only seems to be correct after submitting the form, not on changing the name field; I want this to be valid before having to submit.

How can I get the value to be correct on changing the name field rather than submitting? Note that I found a similar post but that uses Formik, which is not what I want to use: [Formik + Yup: How to immediately validate form before submit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61882834/formik-yup-how-to-immediately-validate-form-before-submit)

The Yup settings:

```
const schema = Yup.object().shape({
    name: Yup.string()
      .required("Required")
      .min(3, "Enter at least 3 characters")
  });
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    setError,
    formState: { errors },
    trigger
  } = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(schema)
    // mode: "onTouched",
    // reValidateMode: "onChange"
  });
```

The name changing function:

```
  const onNameChange = async ({ target: { value } }) => {
    const valid = await trigger("name");
    console.log("valid", valid, "value", value);
    if (!valid) {
      // @todo: bug here? valid only correct after submitting
      return;
    }
    getPokemon(value);
    setShowPokemon(false);
  };
```

The demo form:

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit /*, onError*/)}>
        <input
          {...register("name", { required: true })}
          name="name"
          placeholder="Enter a pokemon"
          onChange={onNameChange}
        />
        <button type="submit" onClick={onSubmit}>
          Show Pokemon
        </button>
        {errors.name && <p>{errors.name.message}</p>}
      </form>
```

I've made a live demo on codesandbox that should be helpful:

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-odwi2?file=/Pokemon.js

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you aren't updating the RHF state after changing your name `<input />`, because you are overriding the `onChange` prop, which is returned from  `{...register('name')}`.

So basically you have to options here:

1. use `setValue` to update the RHF state value for `name` inside your `onNameChange` callback
2. use `<Controller />` component

You can read about it in this [discussion](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/discussions/3387) on GitHub.

This how it would be implemented for the second option using `<Controller />`:

```js
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit /*, onError*/)}>
  <Controller
    name="name"
    control={control}
    defaultValue=""
    render={({ field: { value, onChange, ...field } }) => (
      <input
        {...field}
        onChange={({ target: { value } }) => {
          onChange(value);
          onNameChange(value);
        }}
        placeholder="Enter a pokemon"
      />
    )}
  />

  <button type="submit" onClick={onSubmit}>
    Show Pokemon
  </button>
  {errors.name && <p>{errors.name.message}</p>}
</form>
```

[image: Edit React PlayGround (forked)]

Comment: That's a very helpful explanation, thank you. Logging the input using watch also proved that you're right

Comment: trying to use the <Control /> approach with a select

Answer (score 0):

You have to just pass an arg in register function like

```
    const [credentials, setCredentials] = useState({
        // ....
            emailAddress: '',
        });
      
    const handleChange = (e: any) => {
            setCredentials({
                ...credentials,
                [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
            });
    };
```

```html
    <div className='md:flex md:items-center mb-6'>
        <Input
            isRequired
            aria-label='emailAddress'
            startContent={<EnvelopeIcon className='h-4 w-6 text-dark' />}
            size={'sm'}
            type='email'
            isInvalid={errors?.emailAddress}
            color={errors?.emailAddress ? 'danger' : 'default'}
                        errorMessage={errors?.emailAddress && errors.emailAddress.message}
            {...register('emailAddress', {
                onChange: (e) => {
                        handleChange(e);},
            })}
            label='Your email address'
            variant='bordered'
            value={credentials.emailAddress}/>
   </div>
```