# Disable button till all the form fields get filled in Formik

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, formik

I am using Formik form. I have two fields inside it. I need to disable the save button till both the fields get filled.

```
<Formik initialValues={initialValues} validationSchema={validate} onSubmit={() => this.handleSubmit()}>
  {({ values, handleChange, handleSubmit, setValues, isSubmitting }) => (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} noValidate>
      <div>
        <div onClick={this.showDrawer}>
          <h6>Select Company </h6>
          <input name="customer" readOnly placeholder="Select" value={values.customer} type="text" />
        </div>
        <ErrorMessage component="span" name="customer" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <div onClick={this.showDrawer}>
          <h6>Select Driver</h6>
          <input name="driver" readOnly placeholder="Select" value={values.driver} type="text" />
        </div>
        <ErrorMessage component="span" name="driver"/>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" disabled={isSubmitting}>
        Save
      </button>
    </form>
  )}
</Formik>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React formik form validation: How to initially have submit button disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59443005/react-formik-form-validation-how-to-initially-have-submit-button-disabled)

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi Tried that but did not work

Comment: Did you check this ? https://github.com/formium/formik/issues/147

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi The solution in the github worked for me. But still formik itself should give some own way

Comment: If you think there is no way , you can open an issue in the github.

Answer (score 5):

```
<Formik initialValues={initialValues} validationSchema={validate} onSubmit={() => this.handleSubmit()}>
  {({ values, handleChange, handleSubmit, setValues, isSubmitting, dirty, isValid }) => (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} noValidate>
      <div>
        <div onClick={this.showDrawer}>
          <h6>Select Company </h6>
          <input name="customer" readOnly placeholder="Select" value={values.customer} type="text" />
        </div>
        <ErrorMessage component="span" name="customer" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <div onClick={this.showDrawer}>
          <h6>Select Driver</h6>
          <input name="driver" readOnly placeholder="Select" value={values.driver} type="text" />
        </div>
        <ErrorMessage component="span" name="driver"/>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" disabled={!(dirty && isValid)}>
        Save
      </button>
    </form>
  )}
</Formik>
```

Comment: please provider an explanation how this code solve the problem.

Comment: Though I feel the button part should be:
 ```<button type="submit" disabled={dirty && !isValid)}>Save</button>```

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  ({ errors, ...others }) => (
  ...other components
  <button type="submit" disabled={isSubmitting || Object.keys(errors).length > 0}>
    Save
  </button> )
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.