# How to conditionally disable the submit button with react-hook-form?

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

Couldn't find a solution.
I'm using `react-hook-form` and I want to disable the submit button when the forms are empty and enable as long as all forms have atleast something written in them.
How would I do that using `react-hook-form`?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```
const { 
    register, 
    handleSubmit, 
    formState: { isSubmitting, isDirty, isValid } // here
  } = useForm({ mode: "onChange" })


<button
  type="submit"
  disabled={!isDirty || !isValid} // here
>
  Comment
</button>
```

Comment: or you could get form state directly from `const { isDirty, isValid } = useFormState();` if used in nested components

Answer (score 33):

The best solution I found so far using `formState` and by setting the mode to `onChange`.

```
 const { register, handleSubmit, formState } = useForm({
    mode: "onChange"
  });
```

And on the submit button:

```
<button disabled={!formState.isValid}/>
```

Based on this issue: https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/issues/77

**onChange mode explanation from the documentation:**

> Validation will trigger on the change event with each input, and lead to multiple re-renders. Warning: this often comes with a significant impact on performance.

Answer (score 3):

you can use `formState` => `isDirty` which means form is been modified.

https://react-hook-form.com/api#formState

here is a working example for `formState` below:

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-v6-formstate-ht098?file=/src/index.jsx:423-432

`<input disable={formState.isDirty} type="submit" />`

Comment: What if i want to disabled the submit button again after submit successful. I dont see that case mention the the doc. Thanks for the `react-hook-form` , it is a great lib.

Comment: This does not seem to work with controllers when using third party libraries

Answer (score 1):

```
const { 
    register, 
    handleSubmit, 
    formState: { isSubmitting, isDirty } // <== isDirty
  } = useForm({ defaultValues: { ... } }) // <== defaultValues - leave your form values empty in your case


<button
  type="submit"
  disabled={!isDirty} // <== Once form is touched, this changes
>
  submit
</button>
```

With the above, until the form is touched, the submit button is disabled.

You can combine with `isValid` to ensure the form cannot be submitted until all validations pass.

Answer (score 0):

Close but I think the logic is slightly off from the other comments. The key is to use the `&&` operator. Credit to the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59676720/2190488) with the Formik library.

```js
const { formState: { errors, isDirty, isValid } } = useForm()
///...
<button type="submit" disabled={!isDirty && !isValid}>
Continue
</button>
```

Comment: So when the form is dirty, yet invalid (false && true), it won't be disabled anymore? I don't think this is a suitable answer for most use cases.

Comment: I think that should be `||`.